# VB.NET one-liner set property on item in dynamic array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In VB.NET, on one line of code, dynamically create an array based on some already existing `TextBox` objects, select one textbox by index, and set its `Text` property.

Example on two lines:

```
Dim textboxes = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
textboxes(someIndex).Text = "abc"
```

Syntax error trying one line:

```
{TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}(someIndex).Text = "abc"
```

Just looking for the cleanest one-liner.

I occasionally run into different forms of this.  I used TextBox to keep the question simpler.  It could be objects that aren't controls and aren't named similarly, such as like:

```
{itemDefault, itemFromSql, itemFromXml}(someIndex).SomeProperty = someValue
```

*(And I'm not asking for reasons to instead make this more than one line of code.)*

Comment: Are we allowed to be curious why you want it all on one line, as long as we don't try to tell you to do otherwise? :-)

Comment: Oh... you're sneaky...  If it's something I can do on one line without being too confusing, then I want to, since mentally it is one action (get the 4th textbox and set its text).  My failed attempt above seems like it should work but doesn't, whereas I think I've done something similar in C#.

Comment: Sounds like a good case for a helper function, which will have the bonus of self-documenting what your code is doing as well as saving you from repeating your code.

Comment: I added another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48352762/119418) and included your idea in the form of a new `Choose()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerable to the rescue!

```
Enumerable.ElementAt({TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}, someIndex).Text = "abc"
```

Another cool function I discovered is `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault()`, which returns the datatype's default value (such as null) if the index is out of range of the array.

Comment: I’m glad that you found the solution, I’m sure that’ll help me at some point.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can think of is to wrap the array in some other call, such as CType() or DirectCast(), which works but its purpose isn't clear to others.

```
DirectCast({TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}, TextBox())(someIndex).Text = "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the properties during the initialization:

```
Dim textboxes() As TextBox = {New TextBox() With {.Text = "abc"}, New TextBox() With {.Text = "def", 'etc...}
```

**Update**
I see in your comment that the TextBox controls are already created; I misunderstood, I thought that the TextBox controls were also being created dynamically.

You aren't able to do this during the initialization of the array. Simply put, you cannot access the members of the collection before the collection is created.

If I had to guess as to why casting the collection first works, it may be that casting the array completes the initialization allowing you to access its members.

Comment: Well, I am working with objects already initialized.  I'll update the question to indicate that.

Comment: Based on the syntax, it's reasonable to suspect the syntax should work, as it would first construct the array, not reference it in a variable, and then retrieve an item from the array and set a property.  I believe this works in C# and is just something about VB.NET that isn't supported (either intentionally for some reason or just haven't bothered to support it).  I admit it's not a common scenario and most people don't run into this.  A similar scenario that also doesn't work is: (new SomeClass()).ExecuteSomething, although that can be solved by preceding it with a "Call" command.

Answer (score 1):

If these are all located within your form you could look for them by name (that is, assuming that all of them have the name `TextBox#` - where `#` is the number 1, 2, 3, and so on):

```
Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & (someindex + 1), True)(0).Text = "abc"
```

However note that if you give it an index that results in a name of a text box that doesn't exist, this will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Actually I have done this before and it works well, so I upvoted you.  It might be slower I'm guessing but usually probably doesn't matter.  In my private scenario, the objects are not named so consistently, although maybe they should be.  Really though, I just want to know how to dynamically create an array of existing objects and set a property on one of its items.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Bad answer - this doesn't work as a stand-alone statement!!!**

How about this:

```
(New TextBox() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3})(someIndex).Text = "abc"
```

Comment: That doesn't compile either.

Comment: It does for me.  What version of Visual Basic are you using?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, I've tried this with the 4.5.2, 4.6.2, and the 4.7.1 .NET Frameworks, and .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Visual Studio places a single red line under the first parenthesis with a syntax error and doesn't compile.

Comment: Does this work for you?  `Console.WriteLine((New String() {"A", "B", "C"})(2))`  This works for me in VS2017 / .NET 4.7, and in VS2013 / .NET 4.5.1.  Perhaps if you give a little more code context we can figure out why it's complaining for you.

Comment: yes.  VB.NET has a quirk where even though that is valid syntax, it isn't valid as the starting point of a line of code.  That's why my workaround of using Enumerable.ElementAt(...) works, because the array is created and passed in as a parameter.  And the "New String()" part doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Looks like you're right.  I swear I tried it as an assignment, not a function argument, both before and after you said it wasn't working for you.  I wonder what I actually tried (twice!).

Comment: For me, it's easy to miss the single underline and think it accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically VB's `Choose()` function would work, except it has a stench of being backwards compatible with some ancient version of BASIC, due to its index being 1-based, and a datatype of Single for some reason...  And also its return object would have to be wrapped in CType or DirectCast...

A solution based [stone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48328397/vb-net-one-liner-set-property-on-item-in-dynamic-array/48328398#comment83650068_48328397)'s suggestion of creating a wrapper function, and also closely and generically imitating VB's `Choice()` function:

```
Public Shared Function Choose(Of T)(index As Integer, ParamArray choice As T()) As T
    Return choice(index)
End Function
```

Which can then be called like:

```
Choose(someIndex, TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3).Text = "abc"
```